# How to add a next button on a submit form without submitting the form?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to add a next button for the last question.
For example I want to show the first 4 question with the comment, but I 
want to have a next button which will show the 'question #5'.

Right now the when I submit the form works, it insert the values into tables.
What I would like to do is submit the form after the user click on the question 5
which in that page I will have a submit button.

How can I make this happen making look like for the user that they move to a different 
page but it really is the same page?

I also made a  http://jsfiddle.net/3epja/ that has the complete form.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="5">
                 <cfset question = GetEmployeeCSEDepts["csedept_question" & i][GetEmployeeCSEDepts.CurrentRow]>
                   <cfif question neq "">

                       <tr>
                        <cfif i is 1><td>Leadership <br/>
                        <span class="description">Proactive instead of reactive, a good communicator, respectful, organized, consistent, resourceful, open-minded, sets good example</span>
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 2><td>Integrity<br/>
                        <span class="description">Professional, ethical, honest, loyal, sincere, trusted, fair, doing the right thing, genuine</span>
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 3><td>Service<br/>
                        <span class="description">Solution oriented, supportive,honest, loyal, trusted, listened to what is needed, took ownership, responsive, created win-win outcome.</span>
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 4><td>Teamwork<br/>
                        <span class="description">Cooperative and or/supportive of others, reliable/dependable, willing to pitch in and help, partners well with others to achieve a task, shares and contributes expertise.</span>
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 5><td>Overall</td></cfif>


                         <td valign="top">    <div align="center">  <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="5"></div><br></td>
                            <td valign="top"><div align="center">       <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="4.5"></div><br></td>
                            <td valign="top"><div align="center">       <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="4"></div><br></td>
                            <td valign="top">   <div align="center">    <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="3"></div><br></td>




                     </tr>
                  </cfif>
                </cfloop>
```

Comment: You will have to use javascript in some way shape or form to add fields on the fly.  There are lot's of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: well i dont want to 'add' fields, i just want to show the last one 'question 5' when a user would click on a next button

Comment: You can use CSS to hide parts of the form, or use a tabbed interface such as i jQueryUI and have the 'Submit' button check what 'step' you are on and handle showing/hiding what needs to be done, or submit the form.

Comment: For showing/hiding parts of a web page, it' still done with javascript somehow.  Other people have mentioned jQuery.  That's simply a javascript library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a really simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/mf6Eg/

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="panel1">
        <p>First set of questions goes here</p>
        <button type="button" id="btnNext">Next &gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2">
        <p>Second set of questions goes here</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#panel1, #panel2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

#panel2 {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#btnNext').click(function() {
    $('#panel1').hide();
    $('#panel2').show();
});
```

This uses just javascript (jQuery), and with a little work it could handle as many panels as you want.

Comment: on top of the script i put <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.2.1.0.js"></script>  which i get from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js , this should work right, since right now its not working

Comment: What version browser are you testing it on?

Comment: i try all , mostly firefox

Comment: i have figure it out, i didnt know it was a big deal of where i put the the javascript